# Custom Nifi processor throwing build error : Null Pointer Exception from Nifi nar maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I am trying to build custom nifi processor with controller service, I have configured projects setting to build nar files, while building getting following error, this looks to be from nifi libraries, plz let me know is there any solution or workaround exiting for this.This looks to be nif-nar-maven-plugin issue, could problem with version!!

```
[INFO] Generating documentation for NiFi extensions in the NAR... [INFO] Found a dependency on version 1.11.4 of NiFi API
[ERROR] Could not generate extensions' documentation
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create Extension Documentation
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.generateDocumentation (NarMojo.java:596)
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.execute (NarMojo.java:499)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.getRequiredServiceDefinitions (NarMojo.java:708)
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.writeDocumentation (NarMojo.java:634)
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.writeDocumentation (NarMojo.java:605)
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.generateDocumentation (NarMojo.java:577)
at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.execute (NarMojo.java:499)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for custom-processor 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] custom-processor ................................... SUCCESS [ 6.729 s]
[INFO] nifi-sample-api .................................... SUCCESS [ 4.566 s]
[INFO] nifi-sample ........................................ SUCCESS [ 12.118 s]
[INFO] nifi-custom-processors ............................. SUCCESS [ 10.350 s]
[INFO] nifi-custom-nar .................................... FAILURE [ 4.535 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.067 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-06T22:23:28+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-maven-plugin:1.3.1:nar (default-nar) on project nifi-custom-nar: Failed to create Extension Documentation: NullPointerException -> [Help
```

I have used latest Nifi version, the contents of maven-plugin directory find from attachment, any help greatly appreciated[image].

Comment: Would most likely need to see the code for your processors and services and possibly the poms

Comment: @Byan, I have not put my code any thing in the custom processor except adding the service properties, its basic build, and i have not mentioned nif-nar-maven-plugin any where in the pom, its downloading from dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried this reference ? It will be somewhat answer your question . https://medium.com/hashmapinc/creating-custom-processors-and-controllers-in-apache-nifi-e14148740ea

Comment: It is related to the property descriptor that references the service, can you show that?

Comment: @Kaviranga, I have followed same link as reference to build custom processor, but still getting the issue.

Comment: @Byan  Public static final PropertyDescriptor MY_SERVICE  =  new PopertyDescriptor .Builder().name(MY_PROPERTY) .DisplayName("MY property").Description("Example Property").required(true).addValidator(StandardValidators.NONEMPTY_VALIDATOR).build();

Comment: Ok that property doesn't reference a service, it would have identifiesControllerService

Comment: @Byan I did some mess up looks to be I will get back.

Comment: @Byan I did correct the PropertyDescriptor declaration still see the issue is happening                                                                Public static final PropertyDescriptor MY_SERVICE = new PropertyDescriptor                                                    .Builder().name("MY SERVICE")                                      .displayName("My Service")                                           .required(true)                                                                    .IdentifiesControllerService(MyService.class)                 .build();

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following dependency in the nar child project's pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.4</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I wish this worked for me; it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @RussBateman Did you find the reason at that time?

Comment: After asking I've found a problem. A lot of necessary code disappeared from my implementation, e.g. PropertyDescriptors etc. So these errors can also mean, that one just has wrong implementation.

Comment: Sorry, @FedorPetrov, I looked back through my notes and through my git logs and can't remember what I was doing or how I solved it.